# Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field

Tags: android, retrofit

**I am unable to understand what is the issue here :
is it library issue?**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Form-encoded method must contain
>   at least one @Field.
>           for method ApiInterface.hitCheckVersionApi$79c79d47
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
>           at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:11711)
>           at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
>           at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
>           at $Proxy3.hitCheckVersionApi$79c79d47(Unknown Source)
>           at com.shopoholicbuddy.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:1058)

**Here is code sample:**

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("checkversion")
    Call<ResponseBody> hitCheckVersionApi(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> map);
```

**And the implementation code is:**

```
 private void checkForceUpdateAPI() {
        if (AppUtils.getInstance().isInternetAvailable(this)) {
            final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Constants.NetworkConstant.PARAM_VERSION_NAME, getAppVersion(this));
            params.put(Constants.NetworkConstant.PARAM_PLATFORM, "1");
            params.put(Constants.NetworkConstant.PARAM_APP_TYPE, "2");
            ApiInterface apiInterface = RestApi.createService(this, ApiInterface.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.hitCheckVersionApi(params);
            ApiCall.getInstance().hitService(this, call, new NetworkListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int responseCode, String response, int requestCode) {
                    try {
                        VersionUpdateResponse bean = new Gson().fromJson(response, VersionUpdateResponse.class);
                        if (bean.getCode() == 310) {
                            if (bean.getResult().getVersionName() != null && Double.parseDouble(bean.getResult().getVersionName())<=(Double.parseDouble(getAppVersion(SplashActivity.this)))) {
                                showSplashScreen();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this, R.style.DatePickerTheme);
                                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.new_version_available));
                                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.upgrade_to_new_version));
                                builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.update), (dialogInterface, i) -> redirectStore("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shopoholic"));
                                if (bean.getResult().getUpdateType() != null && bean.getResult().getUpdateType().equals("1")) {
                                    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no_thanks), (dialogInterface, i) -> showSplashScreen());
                                }
                                builder.setCancelable(false);
                                builder.show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            showSplashScreen();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        showSplashScreen();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Is this happened in debug or release mode?

Comment: can you please tell me the error reason?

Comment: Apk is not build yet

Comment: If this is happened int the release mode, the reason may be **Proguard**, You need to add the rules into the Proguard file. If its int the debug mode then reason may be different.

Comment: please tell me both solution

Comment: First of all check this

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded-using-fieldmap

Comment: @HemantCTD, [check this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2676)

Comment: @RakeshKumar i also checked this but they sujjest to ask on stackoverflow

Comment: @HemantCTD, ***i set both minifyEnabled and shrinkResources to false on my build.gradle and it worked: minifyEnabled false***

Comment: can you show the sample

Comment: is my code is right?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? and how?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in RELEASE build. Adding proguard rules will resolve it.
https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro
If you got this error in DEBUG build, then it's something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also mean, not in the case of this post, that you are using     @FormUrlEncoded without @Field like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@GET("item")
suspend fun getItems(): Response<MutableList<Item>>
```

So delete @FormUrlEncoded

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I got the same issue in my Android Project.
**But** the great news is that the issue was resolved.

I upgraded my project with the newer version support. But I can't upgrade the Retrofit libraries.

- **Update your Retrofit libraries.**
- **Optional** - There is required **minifyEnable false** also required sometimes (In app level gradle file).  If you want to set **true** this then you need to write proguard rules.

[Android](https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/)   -  [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/hardik-chitroda-768873139/)